# Salesforce Knowledge Article Export with Images Issue

Tags: salesforce

I am working on moving our Salesforce Knowledge Base to another system.  When I go to export, I select the kav export and get the articles.  However, I cannot find how to translate from the source of the images in the articles to the images downloaded in the export.  Google has not been helpful with this either.

Has anyone been able to translate the spreadsheets to map from file to the referenced file in the KB article?

What I did:

Take the source file name in the image tag and look up in the spreadsheets.  No direct translation.